# How to save R xtable(data.frame) output in .tex document?

Tags: debian, latex, r

I want to present R data.frame output as LaTeX table. 
Data structure is `data.frame`. 
Doing `print(DF.tex)`, the output looks fine in STOUT, in contrast to the the file.

Expected output: UTF-8 format

### Code 1

```
DF <- head(iris)
library("xtable") # https://stackoverflow.com/a/9274146/54964
filename.tex <- paste("/home/masi/text.tex")
DF.tex <- xtable(DF)
save(DF.tex, file = filename.tex)
```

Output in the path location: some hexadecimal cryptic

### Code 2

```
f <- file(filename.tex, 'w') # https://stackoverflow.com/a/19837122/54964
cat(file = f, DF.tex, append = TRUE)
```

Output: 0 byte file

### Code 3

I am using many functions in my script, so just in case, using `print()`

```
save(file = filename.tex, print(DF.tex))
```

Output: cryptic hexadecimal file

R: 3.4.0 (backports)
OS: Debian 8.7
Related: Test 2 extented in the theard [How to save R stargazer(data.frame) output in .tex document?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/368575/16920) with the `stargazer` package

Comment: OK, but it's used again in `DF.tex <- xtable(DF)`, which will also fail.

Comment: Thanks, that's much better - hopefully now solved below?

Comment: What if the table is a longtable to be broken over several pages? Do I need to do the work from my master latex document or from R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying out the example code 1, the file produced, 'filename.tex' is actually a gzip file of the R object containing the tex data - to save the text output of the object, non-compressed, use:

```
print(DF.tex, file = "/home/masi/filename.tex", compress = FALSE)
```

For me, testing using `latex2html filename.tex` gives a nicely formatted table.

Comment: I can confirm that your proposal works. - - Can you explain, please, why you cannot use `save()` and `cat()` here?

Comment: I'm not sure what combination of those calls you're referring to, but the `save()` help page states that it saves a binary or ASCII version of the R object, not the printed output.

Comment: `stargazer` approach here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/368575/16920