# How to save R stargazer(data.frame) output in .tex document?

Tags: debian, latex, r

This thread is the continua of the thread [How to save R xtable(data.frame) output in .tex document?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/366637/16920) but with the package `stargazer` where the approach proposed for `xtable` does not work. 
Code

```
DF <- head(iris)
library("stargazer") # https://stackoverflow.com/a/9274146/54964
filename.tex <- paste("/home/masi/text.tex")
DF.tex <- stargazer(DF)
print(DF.tex, file = "/home/masi/filename.tex", compress = FALSE) # https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/368184/16920
```

Output: no .tex file

R: 3.4.0 (backports)
OS: Debian 8.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to capture the console output with `capture.output()`:

```
writeLines(capture.output(stargazer(DF)), filename.tex)
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why those two packages differ so much in giving out the outputs?

Comment: The `xtable` package contains a S3 `print` method for `xtable` objects (`xtable::print.xtable`). `stargazer` doesn't have a `print` method.

Comment: Does it mean that this approach would work also with `xtable`?

Comment: yes, `writeLines(capture.output(xtable::print.xtable(xtable::xtable(iris))), "test.tex")
`

Answer (score 1):

Stargazer has an option to save to file:

```
stargazer(DF, out=filename.tex)
```